# jquery append issue causing duplication

Tags: jquery, append

I am trying to append an element to a div panel with out it duplicating by 2. It works fine if I append to the body, but If I append to a div it adds 2 more.

```
$("#click").click(function () {
    $("#panel1").append(txt_box='<div id="sample" id="input_'+id+'" ><img src="assets/img/bluesticky4.png"/><img src="addClick/remove.png" class="remove"/></div>');
    $("#button_pro").append(txt_box);
    id++;

});


var id=1,txt_box;
    $('#button_pro').on('click','.add',function(){
        $(this).remove();
        txt_box='<div id="sample" id="input_'+id+'" ><img src="assets/img/bluesticky.png"/><img src="addClick/remove.png" class="remove"/></div>';
        $("#button_pro").append(txt_box);
        id++;
    });

    $('#button_pro').on('click','.remove',function(){
        var parent=$(this).parent().prev().attr("id");
        var parent_im=$(this).parent().attr("id");
        $("#"+parent_im).slideUp('medium',function(){
            $("#"+parent_im).remove();

        });
    });


});
</script>
```

Comment: can you add a Fiddle or Plunkr?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v0nni/eba6m6dv/

Comment: I got the duplication to stop. Now i only need the remove() to work.

Comment: Is this what your trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/z8wL6dwk/ the selector in $(selector).on() must exist to work, you can use the secondary selector to target the dynamically included element $(selector).on('click','secondary-selector',function(){})

Comment: Yes! Thanks--exactly! Not sure if I can give you a check mark since someone said this answer is already answered